# Example of Set X which is not well ordered such that $X\times [0,1)$ with dictionary ordered is not Linear Continuum

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Example of Set X which is not well ordered such that $X\times [0,1)$ with dictionary ordered is not Linear Continuum

I had proved following theorem

Set X which is not well ordered then $X\times [0,1)$ with dictionary ordered is  Linear Continuum.

Linear Continuum have the property of LUB and for any 2 point of its there is point between them.

I wanted to know is there converse true or not?

I found all example till that are well ordered

But I was suspicous about converse .

Please give me hint to construct a counterexample

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X \times_{\textrm{lex}} [0,1)$ is a continuum, $X$ must have the property that a non-maximal element has a successor $x^+$: What else can the supremum of $\{x\} \times [0,1)$ else be but $(x^+,0)$, where $(x,x^+)\subseteq X$ is empty? This property is implied by being a well-order, but it might be almost equivalent to what you want. $X=\mathbb{Z}$ is an example: note that $\mathbb{Z} \times_{\textrm{lex}} [0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, a continuum (via $x \to (\lfloor x\rfloor, x - \lfloor x\rfloor )$, e.g., while $\mathbb{Z}$ is not well-ordered.